# sklearn RandomForest: merging random forests votings and make finanl decision

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I built RandomForest (RF) with sklearn package.

My issue is that I have trained RF with same samples with different feature groups.

For example, there are 10,000 samples, and I received data from different Labs.

FR1 is trained with data from Lab1
FR2 is trained with data from Lab2
...
FR5 is trained with data from Lab5

The number of features from each lab is 4,000, so data size from each lab is 10,000 x 4000

Instead of merging all data, I would like to train RFs and make final decision from majority vote. 
Majority vote is not just based on Labs but considering all votes in individual labs.

For example, all models produced 100 trees, then I would like make final decision from 100 * (5 Labs) = 500 trees. Not just majority votes of Labs but majority votes from all trees produced from individual labs.

Could you help me how I can solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: The idea of a randomforest is that each RF is fit and does it's own "vote" based on the trees it contains. I'm not sure what you expect to gain from re-using each individual tree inside each RF. If you're going to do that anyway, I would just refit a new RF on all the data. Otherwise, I would just figure out the optimum way to `rf.predict(new_data)` with each classifier and compare/average the scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RF makes predictions by using averages of predictions across all trees. So, you may take

```
estimators_
```

(it is DecisionTrees; 5 * 100 in your example) from each forest, make predictions from each of it and then average the probabilities/outputs. But I believe that this approach is pretty equal to averaging outputs of all RFs:

```
outputs from forest 1: 0.5, 1, 1.5; average: 1
outputs from forest 2: 1, 1.25, 1.5; average: 1.25

average of forests: (1 + 1.25) / 2 = 1.125
average of trees: (0.5 + 1 + 1.5 + 1 + 1.25 + 1.5) / 6 = 6.75 / 6 = 1.125
```

Or better solution: put some simple model (LinearRegression/LogisticRegression) on the top which takes outputs from each RF and predicts final value. Worked pretty good in some Kaggle competitions. The simple model will help you not to overfit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and suggesting stacking for final decision.